# Pipeline never finishes deploying AWS ECS Fargate Task through codepipeline

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer, awsdeploy

I set up a Fargate ecs service on AWS with multiple target groups and an application load balancer. It runs just as expected.

Then I tried to set up a pipeline using this tutorial

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cd-pipeline.html

and now it is stuck at deployment stage and when I check out the deployments in ECS service. There's one ACTIVE and the other PRIMARY and I can visit both IPs. But the deployment never finishes and both will stay as my pipeline times out. Why is the ACTIVE one never going to drain in this case? Or is it because of the load balancer? I followed this tutorial with a service with single target group and the pipeline works as normal.

Comment: So I tried manually to stop ACTIVE task while deploy is still in progress. Now the pipeline finishes when I stop the ACTIVE task. So the question is how to change the settings so that ACTIVE task can be stopped automatically.

Answer (score 1):

for me it was the:

minimum and maximum healthy percentage.

I changed it to 100 and 200 respectively. This worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

From the description, I suspect your Tasks in PRIMARY group (the new task created as part of deployment) are not getting healthy on the ALB. During deployment, please check the Target groups to confirm the new tasks (by IPs) are healthy.

Once news tasks are healthy on ALB, ECS stops the old tasks / ACTIVE deployment.